# Update a html element from a thread

Tags: c#, html, .net

What is the easiest way to update an HTML element from another thread?

I have a Razor/HTML page with a startJob button which will trigger an ActionResult to start a long process on background thread, from that I want to the background tread to update an Html element of the current status.
How can I do that?

```
    public ActionResult StartJob(int[] instList)
    {

            permissionCheck = new Thread(CheckPermissions);
            permissionCheck.Start();


        var jr = new JsonNetResult();
        jr.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        jr.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        jr.Data = (inQueue <= 0?0:inQueue);

        return jr;
    }


    public void CheckPermissions()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {                
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            //update the html element id status message

        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.Sleep`, it's not guaranteed to wait the minimum amount of time, you should use a `timer`, also why not use `async` tasks?

Comment: If the response has already been sent to the client then you can't modify it from there anymore.  It sounds like you're looking for something like SignalR (web sockets) or at least some kind of AJAX polling solution.  Server-side code can't "modify an HTML element" that's in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async/await` and `tasks` instead of another thread:

```
public async ActionResult StartJob(int[] instList)
{
    await CheckPermissions;

    var jr = new JsonNetResult();
    jr.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    jr.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    jr.Data = (inQueue <= 0?0:inQueue);

    return jr;
}


public async Task CheckPermissions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {                
        //Thread.Sleep(100); // Don't use this
        //update the html element id status message

    }
}
```

Comment: I think he is trying to implement the "update the html element id status message" part and not the long running task part. Ie. dynamically update the web page with a status of how the long running task is going.

Comment: @GeorgeRichardson I was assuming the issue might have been simply from trying to update via another thread, in which case async await could be used to return control when needed. But looking at the other answer I may be wrong all together!

Comment: How will I access the html element inside the async Task function?

Comment: Looking at the other answer, if you're trying to update after you've sent the HTML page, you can't but I'd recommend using Socket.io with NodeJS to create a socket connection, then look at some documentation I wrote on using sockets in C# http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1352/networking#t=201608151719344958842

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really possible out of the box with just C# but there are two ways you could go about implementing this.

1. Use javascript on the page to poll your server for updates, perhaps through a WebAPI controller.
2. Use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to update your page dynamically (also requires javascript running on your page)

Unfortunately dynamically updating a web page isn't really possible without using at least some javascript